# Prove that for positive real number $a,b,c$ such that $abc=1$ the following Inequality holds

Tags: inequality

> Prove that for positive real number $a,b,c$ such that $abc=1$ the following Inequality holds: $$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{a+b+2} + \frac{1}{b+c+2} + \frac{1}{c+a+2} \geq \frac{15}{4} $$

---

Letting $a= \frac{x}{y},b=\frac{y}{z}, c=\frac{z}{x}$, we get the Inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{y}+\frac{x}{z}+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+2}+\frac{1}{\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}+2}+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{z}{x}+2} \geq \frac{15}{4}$$. I tried some algebraic manipulations but those didn't work. I want some instructive hints to make progress. Thank you

Comment: @CalvinLin note that $y/x +z/y + x/z \geq 3$ by am gm. And i tried to write $\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+2}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{y}+1\right)+\left(\frac{y}{z}+1\right)}$. I can't see how to proceed from here though, please only give some subtle hints/ some direction to move forward towards

Comment: Note that $ \sum 1/(a+b+2) \leq 3/4$, so your split inequality doesn't work. You'd need to use $\sum 1/a$ to offset the loss.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I figured that the Inequality $\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+2}+\frac{1}{\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}+2}+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{z}{x}+2} \geq \frac{3}{4}$ is not true, so splitting won't work. Also, is there some general strategy to work with when we have got 1 on numerator and a monstrous expression on the denominator? The first that comes into my mind would probably be AM-HM, but we also have the first 3 terms to deal with, so that most probably won't work here either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're stuck, explain what you've tried with each of these hints, and I can figure out a further hint.

**Hint 1:** Apply CS (Titu's lemma) on $ \sum \frac{1}{ a+b+2 } $ to get a lower bound that depends only on $S =a+b+c$.

> $ \sum \frac{1}{ a+b+2} \geq \frac{ 9}{ 2(a+b+c) + 6 } $.

Because $ \sum \frac{1}{a+b+2} \leq \frac{3}{4}$ (see note below), so we need a way to bound this term from below.
Titu's Lemma is a good first stab for "when we have got 1 [or anything] on numerator and a monstrous expression on the denominator [multiply by anything as needed]", especially if the denominator is cyclic and combining the terms makes it "much nicer".

**Hint 2:** For $abc=1$, $ S = a+b+c \geq 3$.

This should be obvious / well-known, but it motivates the next hint. See if you can deduce Hint 3 without revealing it.

**Hint 3:**

> For $ abc = 1$, show that $\sum \frac{1}{a} \geq \sqrt{3(a+b+c) } = \sqrt{3S}$.

Finally, putting this all together, show that:

> For $ S \geq 3$, $ \sqrt{3S} + \frac{9}{2S + 6 } \geq \frac{15}{4}$.
>  Equality holds iff $S = 3$, which means $ a = b = c = 1$.

If you want to avoid calculus (which was my gut approach given the simplicity), show that $$ \sqrt{3S} + \frac{9}{2S + 6 } \geq \sqrt{3S} + \frac{ 9 } { 4 \sqrt{3S} } \geq \frac{15}{4}.$$

---

Note:

- To show that $ \sum \frac{1}{a+b+2} \leq \frac{3}{4}$, use OP's substitution and work with $ \sum \frac{z}{x+y+2z} \leq \frac{3}{4} \Leftrightarrow \frac{x+y}{x+y+2z} \geq \frac{3}{2}$, which is true by Titu's lemma (applied in a direct manner by multiplying the numerator to the denominator).
- This tells us that we can't simply hope to show separately that $ \sum \frac{1}{a} \geq 3$ (which is true) and $ \sum \frac{1}{a+b+2} \geq \frac{3}{4} $(which is untrue). We need to somehow combine both parts together, using the surplus in the first to offset the deficit in the second.

Comment: The first hint that $ \sum \frac{1}{ a+b+2 } $, is it with the restriction $abc=1$ or just for positive reals in general?

Comment: For positive reals in general. I've added in where I used $abc=1$.

Comment: wait doesn't Titus lemma give lower bound? Also we are working for a lower bound, then why do we need upper bound on $ \sum \frac{1}{a+b+2}$

Comment: I am looking for a lower bound. We don't need an upper bound (and the upper bound is useless for this question). However, it's still good to know that it's bounded above, meaning we can't do the split which is often a first reaction. Hence I proved the upper bound in the notes at the end.

Comment: Ok, so after applying titu and proving the Inequality in hint 3, I have gotten, $ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{a+b+2} + \frac{1}{b+c+2} + \frac{1}{c+a+2} \geq \frac{9}{2S+6}+\sqrt{3S}$. But I need to get an lower bound on this, which we can on the case of $\sqrt{3S}$, but for $\frac{9}{2S+6}$ the Inequality gets reversed (as I have lower bound on $S$). How do I resolve this?

Comment: Remember that we need to "combine both parts". So show that for $ S \geq 3$, $\sqrt{3S} + \frac{9}{2S+6} \geq 15/4$, and equality holds only for $S=3$.   It's true if you graph it with Wolfram, and there are various ways to apply AM-GM if you want to avoid calculus.